# Why doesn't setPos() work when using addPolygon() method?

Tags: c++, qt

Consider this class called ***Hex*** to draw a hexagon :

```
// Hex.h

#include <QGraphicsPolygonItem>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QVector>
#include <QImage>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QPen>


class Hex : public QGraphicsPolygonItem {
public:
    // constructor
    Hex(QGraphicsItem* parent = NULL);

    // getters/setters
    QPolygonF *getHexagon() {return hexagon;}
    QBrush *getBrush() {return brush;}

protected:
    QBrush *brush;
    QPolygonF *hexagon;

};
```

and

```
// Hex.cpp

#include "hex.h"

Hex::Hex(QGraphicsItem *parent) {

    // set Points
    QVector<QPointF> hexPoints;
    hexPoints << QPointF(1, 0) << QPointF(0, 1)  << QPointF(0, 2)
              << QPointF(1, 3) << QPointF(2, 2)  << QPointF(2 ,1);

    // scale the poly
    int SCALE_BY = 40;
    for (size_t i = 0, n = hexPoints.size(); i < n ; i++) {
        hexPoints[i] *= SCALE_BY;
    }

     //create a QPyolygon with the scaled points
      hexagon = new QPolygonF(hexPoints);


    // draw the polygon
    setPolygon(*hexagon);

}
```

In `main.cpp` :

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "hex.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsView *view = new  QGraphicsView();

    Hex *hex0 = new Hex();
    Hex *hex1 = new Hex();

    hex0->setPos(400, 400);
    hex1->setPos(300, 300);

    scene->addItem(hex0);
    scene->addItem(hex1);

    scene->setSceneRect(0,0 , 1024, 768);
    view->setScene(scene);

    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Ok. this is ok and setPos works fine.

But using addPolygon instead of addItem to set picture for the hexagons results in setPos not working and all the hexagons cover each other at the first coordinates given to them.

Like this :

```
// main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "hex.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsView *view = new  QGraphicsView();

    Hex *hex0 = new Hex();
    Hex *hex1 = new Hex();

    hex0->setPos(400, 400);
    hex1->setPos(300, 300);

    // set picture for hexagons:
    QBrush* brush = new QBrush(QImage("image.png"));

    scene->addPolygon(*hex0->getHexagon(), QPen(Qt::black) ,*brush);
    scene->addPolygon(*hex1->getHexagon(), QPen(Qt::black) ,*brush);

    scene->setSceneRect(0,0 , 1024, 768);
    view->setScene(scene);

    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Why does `setPos()` has this behavior and how to move the ***pictured*** hexagons.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: graphicsItem has a paint function as virtual , you can draw everything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setPos () does not modify the QPolygonF but moves the item in scene coordinates, instead QPolygonF are drawn with respect to the internal coordinate system of the item. Therefore, if you want to observe the initial behavior, you have 2 options:

1. Move the QGraphicsPolygonItem:

   ```cpp
   QGraphicsPolygonItem *p0 = scene->addPolygon(*hex0->getHexagon(), QPen(Qt::black) ,*brush);
   QGraphicsPolygonItem *p1 = scene->addPolygon(*hex1->getHexagon(), QPen(Qt::black) ,*brush);

   p0->setPos(400, 400);
   p1->setPos(300, 300);
   ```
2. Move the QPolygonF:

   ```cpp
   scene.addPolygon((*hex0->getHexagon()).translated(400, 400), QPen(Qt::black));
   scene.addPolygon((*hex0->getHexagon()).translated(300, 300), QPen(Qt::black));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from the fact that `QGraphicsPolygonItem` already has a `QPolygonF` and a `QBrush` member, you don't need extra ones.

Not only that, but `addPolygon` constructs a whole new `QGraphicsPolygonItem`:

> Creates and adds a polygon item to the scene, and returns the item pointer. The polygon is defined by `polygon`, and its pen and brush are initialized to `pen` and `brush`.

I would suggest that `Hex` shouldn't be a *class*, it should be a *function*:

```
QGraphicsSceneItem * makeHex(QPointF pos, int scale = 40) {
    QVector<QPointF> hexPoints{ QPointF(1, 0), QPointF(0, 1), QPointF(0, 2), QPointF(1, 3), QPointF(2, 2), QPointF(2 ,1) };

    // scale the poly
    for (auto & point : hexpoints) {
        point *= scale;
    }

    auto * hex = new QGraphicsPolygonItem();
    hex->setPolygon(hexPoints);
    hex->setPos(pos);
    hex->setBrush(QImage("image.png"));
    
    return hex;
}
```

Or

```
QGraphicsSceneItem * addHex(QGraphicsScene *scene, int scale = 40) {
    QVector<QPointF> hexPoints{ QPointF(1, 0), QPointF(0, 1), QPointF(0, 2), QPointF(1, 3), QPointF(2, 2), QPointF(2 ,1) };

    // scale the poly
    for (auto & point : hexpoints) {
        point *= scale;
    }

    return scene->addPolygon(hexpoints, QPen(Qt::black), QImage("image.png"));
}
```